# How to match the index with two different Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have two Dataframes like these:

|  | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 150 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 250 |
| 4 | 300 |

and

|  | data2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

I'd like to make a new Dataframe like this:

|  | data | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | 2 |
| 3 | 250 | 3 |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')` if your left columns are index

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` and `dropna`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).dropna().astype({**df1.dtypes, **df2.dtypes})
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   data  data2
1   150      1
2   200      2
3   250      3
```

Or, even shorter:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', right_index=True, left_index=True)
```